# Android studio null value entry: sourceOutputDir=null

Tags: android, android-studio

I am experiencing an odd error when I try to build my android studio project.

I haven't changed anything significant in my project but suddenly I am receiving a error:

> *Exception is:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: sourceOutputDir=null

The build always fails and I have been unable to find anyone who has a similar issue.

If anyone has any ideas what could be causing this issue that would at least point me in the right direction.

I have tried clearing my cache and restarting android studio multiple times and rebuilding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the .gradle directory  in the root project directory.
After that,clean your project and rebuild your project.